# Get rid of excess stroke "points" in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Im pretty new to Adobe Illustrator so please bear with me. Im trying to create a low poly art but Im not going to fill the shapes instead Im gonna use stroke. My problem is that I want to get rid of the excess "point", the one that are in circled in red, and I need your help to make it look like the one in circled in green.

Thank you so much.

Comment: In the Stroke panel, try the **Corner** option: Rounded or Bevel Join, and see if it that would be okay for you :')
Also, play a bit with **Stroke Alignments**.

http://www.automotiveillustrations.com/tutorials/tutorialimages/illustrator-line-corner-attributes.jpg

Answer (score 2):

In the "Stroke" options box change the corner type, or reduce the limit  if you want to keep using the "Miter Join" corner and get rid of pointy corners
[image]